# Strange "INavigatorContent" error compiling in 4.0

Tags: flex4, upgrade, halo

I've recently decided to try an upgrade to 4.0.  The only error I still can't work out is this one:

"The children of Halo navigators must implement INavigatorContent"

I seem to be getting it on all my ViewStacks that have validators.

```
<mx:ViewStack xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
 <mx:NumberValidator id="systolicValidator"
      source="{systolic}"
      required="true"
         property="text"
      minValue="10"
      maxValue="300"
      domain="int"/>
 <mx:NumberValidator id="diastolicValidator"
      source="{diastolic}"
      required="true"
      property="text"
      minValue="10"
      maxValue="200"
      domain="int"/>
 <mx:TextInput id="systolic"/>
 <mx:TextInput id="diastolic"/>
    ...
</ViewStack>
```

The error gets thrown on the validator tags.  My compiler is set to "flex 3 compatibility mode" and my theme is set to Halo (default).

This seems like it should be a really straight forward fix, so I hate to spin my wheels on it for too long.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some reading about Flex 4, it would seem that all non-visual elements should go in these tags:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

(xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009")
```

The error was kinda strange.  However, after some cleanup, I got a better error:

> '*' declaration must be contained
>   within the `<Declarations>` tag since
>   it does not implement
>   'mx.core.IUIComponent'.

Much, much more helpful.  I'll post again if I find the reason for the strange error I was getting before.

Answer (score 1):

http://bharatria.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/migration-from-flex-3-to-flex-4/

That is a great link that I found while updating my app from flex 3 to 4.  It can be a bit of a headache, and I recommend reading up on Spark and Halo and all that stuff.